# Equality test on three or more objects

Tags: ruby, equality

If I have three or more objects like so:

```
a = 4
b = 4
c = 4
d = 2
```

what would be a clean ruby-style way of determining whether they are all equal? Any bespoke methods for running equality tests on three or more elements?

I suppose I could do something like this:

```
arrays = [a,b,c,d].map{|x| [x]}
arrays.first == arrays.reduce(:&) ? true : false
```

which appears to work, but feels sort of ham handed, and might be difficult for other developers to read.

Comment: Not to mention your method would really only work with integers.

Comment: Sure about that? `arrays = ["a", "a", "a", "b"].map { |x| [x] }; arrays.first == arrays.reduce(:&) ? true : false` would work I think

Comment: What do you mean by n + 2? What is n?

Comment: I suppose its n+3. because n could be 0. I basically mean `>2`. I'll just change it to that in the title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[a,b,c,d].any?{|x| x != a}
```

or

```
array.any?{|x| x != array.first}
```

Alternatively, the #all? method may read more intuitively for some:

```
array.all? {|x| x == array.first }
```

Comment: The question was "all are equal" not any or one of is equal.

Comment: Either way works. I think the `any?` method is much more commonly used though

Comment: @guitarman By the transitive property of equality, proving one proves the other.  (If your definition of equality is not transitive, you done screwed up, son.)

Answer (score 5):

```
[a, b, c, d].group_by(&:itself).length == 1
# => false
```

or

```
[a, b, c, d].chunk(&:itself).to_a.length == 1
# => false
```

or

```
[a, b, c, d].chunk_while(&:==).to_a.length == 1
# => false
```

or the naive:

```
[a, b, c, d].uniq.length == 1
```

I was reminded of `one?`. Provided that you do not have any falsy element, the above can be written:

```
[a, b, c, d].uniq.length.one?
```

Comment: I like the last one particularly. That's just as good as anything else I've seen

Comment: You forgot `require 'set'; [a,b,c,d].to_set.size==1`, if, as in the example, the values are comparable, `[a,b,c,d].minmax==[a,a]` and, of course, `slice_when` :-).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer by @kipar is better by all means, but for the sake of “doing it the way you started” I would post this here:

```
[a, b, c, d].reduce { |r, e| r == e && r } && true
```